# How to change minimum and default size (surface area) of Windows Sticky Notes

Tags: windows-10, sticky-notes

Last week, for no apparent reason, the Sticky Notes on my Windows 10 desktop grew about 3 to 4 times larger in size (surface area).  Now a sticky note is about 3" x 3" on my 24" desktop, taking up far too much real estate. I can't shrink them back down to a reasonable size.  Is there any way to control the minimum and default size of Sticky Notes?

Comment: I recently had to install Windows from scratch and I noticed that sticky notes are back to a more reasonable size and font size.

Comment: This is ridiculous, after I reinstalled WIndows I can no longer choose background colour of the notes.